# A simple Properties exercise #java

Tags: java, properties

I have a simple Properties exercise
1. Read the time of program run from a configuration document ProgramRunCounter.ini
2. Each time the program run, add one more time
3. Modify the information in document

Here is the code:

```
class ProgramRunCounter {

public static void counter() throws IOException{        
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    File f = new File("ProgramRunCounter.ini");
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw;

    String key = "times";
    String value;
    int counter;

    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("File created");
    }

    //Problem is here
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    prop.load(br);
    value = prop.getProperty(key);      
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    if (value != null) {
        counter = Integer.parseInt(value);
        System.out.println("This program has run " + counter + " times");
        counter++;
        value = String.valueOf(counter);
        prop.setProperty(key, value);
        prop.store(bw, "One more time run!");
    } else {
        prop.setProperty(key, "1");
        prop.store(bw, "First time run!");
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();
}

}

public class PropertiesDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProgramRunCounter.counter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

It works well, but problem is if i change the order of the codes like this, it can't work anymore

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
prop.load(br);
value = prop.getProperty(key);
```

So why? 
It doesn't allow insert `bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));` between `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));` and `prop.load(br);`?
What is the principle?

Comment: File lock. You likely need to finish reading, close the reader, then open the writer.

Comment: This may be a good excuse to use a `RandomAccessFile`

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the details. First let me just say, that you may want to just use the "new" (not soo new anymore) IO file API (i.e. `Files.newBufferedReader` / `Files.newBufferedWriter(f.toPath()`), ...). Not a must, but it makes things easier.

If you look at the javadoc of [`newBufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) you see the following:

> Opens or creates a file for writing, returning a BufferedWriter that may be used to write text to the file in an efficient manner. The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened. If no options are present then this method works as if the [CREATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE), [TRUNCATE_EXISTING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#TRUNCATE_EXISTING), and [WRITE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#WRITE) options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing [regular-file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) to a size of 0 if it exists.

That efficiency is probably the reason why you do not see any content anymore while you are reading the file (here I assume the same efficiency is also applied under the hood, if you just use your own instantation of `BufferedWriter` with `FileWriter` which uses a `FileOutputStream` with `append=false`. If you follow all the calls you end up in a native method, so unfortunately I can't say for sure).

Now if you use `Files.newBufferedWriter` and you just alter the `OpenOption` to say [`SYNC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#SYNC) or something other then `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, the reader is able to load the properties again regardless of which initialization comes first, e.g.

```
br = Files.newBufferedReader(f.toPath());
bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(f.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
```